# SharePoint Online Modern Site-Edit /View list item- HttpRequest failed error

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have one list on SharePoint Online site.It was working fine and suddenly users not able to open the items. It gives below error

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you  give us more details. May be check the browser's console log for errors, or the network tab to see which http request fails...

Comment: Did you customize the list form using Power Apps? If yes, are you getting error while using any connector/method?

Comment: Any updates about this post ? I have the same problem on a Sharepoint list.
It's a Sharepoint form, not a powerapps. In the browser console, there are some errors like
"Refused to get unsafe header "" "
With a list of headers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try clearing browser cache and cookies in your browser. Make sure you are clearing cache & cookies for "all time".

   **References**:

   1. [Delete cookies in Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/delete-cookies-in-microsoft-edge-63947406-40ac-c3b8-57b9-2a946a29ae09)
   2. [How to manage and clear your cache and cookies in Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/learning-center/how-to-manage-and-clear-your-cache-and-cookies?form=MA13I2)
   3. [Clear cache & cookies in Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050)
2. Re-login your to your SharePoint site
3. Open your SharePoint and then list forms, it should work for you now.